# Where to download hudson library?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to modify a jenkins plugin called [Files Found Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Files+Found+Trigger). But after I downloaded the source code from [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin), I found there are lots of lines started with `import hudson.XXX`. And I have no clue where to get the hudson library.

I thought maybe I could find some information at [Jenkins Plugin Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial). But it seems that the tutorial doesn't mention about where to get the library.

Anyone can help?

Comment: doesnt the source of the plugin have build/dependency management? try using this jar <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.hudson.main/hudson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.hudson.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>hudson-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Looking at the pom.xml for the project, https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml. maven should be used and it is child of Jenkins plugin, so `mvn install` should be sufficient. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do anything, the Jenkins core has loads of references to java packages pointing to `hudson.XXX`. This is for legacy reasons, Jenkins used to be called Hudson. When the splitting of the project and renaming to Jenkins was done, the java package structure and names was kept in order to maintain backwards comparability for plugins (otherwise all plugins would have to be updated).

In case you've got compilation errors due to this, then something is wrong with your setup, ensure that the maven dependencies are correct as mishadoff says.

Answer (score 2):

From [here (Upgrading from Hudson to Jenkins)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Upgrading+from+Hudson+to+Jenkins):

> **Jenkins is basically a drop-in replacement to Hudson.**
>
> It's the continuation of the **same code base**, in same package structure. There **has been no major surgery** since the rename, and the **rename really only affected what's shown in the UI**. As such, it understands the same set of environment variables, same system properties, and the same information in the home directory. So if you rename `jenkins.war` as `hudson.war`, and simply overwrite your `hudson.war`, the upgrade is complete.

- So my conclusion is: just rename `hudson` to `jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

Every jenkins plugin should refer to parent object in `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

You can find more examples at official git plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L3

UPDATE: The plugin `Files Found Trigger` you're trying to modify, uses `parent` dependency in `pom.xml` https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L4

All `import hudson.*` statements, come exactly from that lib:

[image: screenshot]